# Why is mouseonhover javascript is not working with classes but works on ids?

Tags: javascript

Why is mouse on hover in javascript is not working with classes but works on ids?

for example,

```
 window.onload = function() {
    var myIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('myIcon'); //does not work
    myIcon.onmouseover = function() {
        // do something
        return false;
    };
};   

but

window.onload = function() {

    var myIcon = document.getElementsByID('myIcon'); //works 

    myIcon.onmouseover = function() {
        // do something
        return false;
    };
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two variables of the same name, which is redeclaring and reassigning `myIcon`. Also, `getElementsByID` is not a function, `getElementById` or `getElementsById` is. `getElementsById` then returns a NodeList with an 'array' of elements. Finally, `getElementsByClassName` also returns a NodeList. Both are array-like so you must treat it like so.

Here's an example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hf5u1z03/2/), note that `getElementsByClassName` in the example only applies to the first element with the class `myIcon`. You can use a for loop to loop through all elements and change their listeners.

```js
var myIcon_class = document.getElementsByClassName('myIcon')[0]; //note, gets first element
var myIcon = document.getElementById('myIcon')
    
myIcon.onmouseover = function() {
    alert("hovered on ID!");
    return false;
};
    
myIcon_class.onmouseover = function() {
 alert("hovered on class!");
    return false;
};
```

```html
<span id="myIcon">Id span!</span>
<span class="myIcon">Class span!</span>
```

Comment: oops sorry, I am actually using one myIcon variable it was just for illustration, I'm editing my question.